# How can I take a user inputted date instead of the current date in the Calendar class in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

I'm working on an assignment, and my goal is to create a class that prints the day of the week given a date. When prompted for input, if the user enters nothing, the program is stopped. Otherwise, if the user enters a date, the program provides the day of the week and then continues to re-prompt the user. The date the user inputs will be in the format of m d y, or for example, 1 10 2017 for January 10th, 2017.

What I have so far does everything I need, except it uses the current day, month, and year instead of the user inputted day, month, and year.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindDayOfWeek {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Repeatedly enter a date (m d y) to get the day of week. Terminate input with a blank line.");
    String date = s.nextLine();

    while (true) {

        if (date.isEmpty()) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else {  

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            String[] days = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

            System.out.println("Day of week is " + days[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1]);

            System.out.println("Repeatedly enter a date (m d y) to get the day of week. Terminate input with a blank line.");
            date = s.nextLine();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I know what needs to be replaced is the second to last chunk of code that says c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), however I do not know what I can use to replace it in order to get the user inputted date.

I know there are other packages that can solve the same problem, however, I'm required to use the Calendar class whether I like it or not.

Comment: Any reason why you are sticking to the long outdated `Calendar` class? Today we have so much better. For your program I warmly recommend `LocalDate` from [the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I wish I could tell you. Instructor requires the Calendar class to be used. Believe me I know it isn't the best way to achieve my goal here.

Comment: The instructor may be after [the three-arg `set` method in the `Calendar` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-). Beware that it expects a 0-based month number, so subtract 1 from the user input before calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Calendar use the [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    LocalDate inputDate;

    while(true){
      System.out.print("Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy:");
      String date = scanner.next();
      try {
        inputDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        break;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Please input the date in the correct format");
      }
    }

    System.out.println("The day of week is " + inputDate.getDayOfWeek().name());
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy: 92/23/2344
ERROR: Please input the date in the correct format
Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy: 11/26/2019
The day of week is TUESDAY
```

**However if you really need to use Calendar and want to use something resembling your existing code, try this:**

***N.B.*** Pay attention to the line `formatter.setLenient(false);` which ensures strict parsing, such that input must match the EXACT format.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    formatter.setLenient(false);
    Date inputDate;

    while(true){
      System.out.print("Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy:");
      String date = scanner.nextLine();
      try {
        inputDate = formatter.parse(date);
        break;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Please input the date in the correct format");
      }
    }

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(inputDate);
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    String[] days = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

    System.out.println("The day of week is " + days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy: 92/23/2344
ERROR: Please input the date in the correct format
Enter a date in the format of MM/dd/yyyy: 11/26/2019
The day of week is Tuesday
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I'm required to use the Calendar class. That's the main goal.

Comment: @Brian See my updated answer it has the code for using the Calendar class as you require.

Answer (score 3):

### Minimize the use of outdated API

[shash678’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554876/5772882) is correct, also in recommending `java.time` over the long outdated `Calendar` class that you are required to use. I just wanted to add one point here: even though you are required to use the `Calendar` class, it doesn’t necessarily imply you also need to use its outdated friends `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The latter may be the most troublesome of them all and certainly one to avoid.

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M d u");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Repeatedly enter a date (m d y) to get the day of week."
            + " Terminate input with a blank line.");
    String date = s.nextLine();
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, inputFormatter);

    // the easy way to get day-of-week would be ld.getDayOfWeek(),
    // but we are required to use Calendar
    // (any ZoneId will do for atStartOfDay(), I just prefer to provide one)
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from(ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    int numberOfDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // display
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
    // Calendar’s dayOfWeek starts from 1 = Sunday;
    // for DayOfWeek.of() we need to start from 1 = Monday
    if (numberOfDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    } else {
        dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(numberOfDayOfWeek - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Day of week is "
            + dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.US));
```

Sample session:

```
Repeatedly enter a date (m d y) to get the day of week. Terminate input with a blank line.
10 5 2017
Day of week is Thursday
```

I left out the repeat until an empty line is entered since you seem to be handling this fine already.

While the above is certainly not what your instructor was after, in real life the requirement to use a specific outdated class typically comes from using a legacy API that requires and/or gives you an instance of that old class. In such a case I recommend you minimize the use of the old API and use the modern one to the greatest extend possible. So in the code I convert to `Calendar` only in the last moment before finding the day-of-week. Whether you convert from `Date` to `Calendar` or from `LocalDate` to `Calendar` doesn’t make any great difference to the complexity of the code, so you might as well do yourself the favor of using the modern `LocalDate`.

I do add a little extra complexity by converting back from the `int` from the `Calendar` to the modern `DayOfWeek` enum, which I use for displaying the day name. You can leave out this part if you want. I included it just to demonstrate that there is a way to avoid reinventing the wheel when converting from `int` to day name.

Comment: Correct Answer, but I want to emphasize that we normally would never mix the java.time classes with the old legacy date-time classes. The only exception is converting between the new and old types at the edges of old code not yet updated to the java.time classes. The Date and Calendar classes are an awful mess and should be avoided. In real work stick to the java.time classes only.