# calendar.getDisplayName returning the wrong day

Tags: java, calendar

Below is my program and it is returning the wrong day name when I enter the related month, date and year.

What I am missing here?

**My Program**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = in.next();
        String day = in.next();
        String year = in.next();

        System.out.println(getDay(day, month, year));
    }

    private static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
        return calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
09
24
2018
Wednesday
```

It should be returning "Monday", as that is the current day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated and poorly designed. I recommend you forget about the trouble with it and instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your users may prefer to type the date on one line as `2018-09-24` (or a perhaps better localized format for their locale). So you may use `String dateString = in.next();` and `LocalDate.parse(dateString).getDayOfWeek()`. If you prefer to input three numbers, use `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`, no adding or subtracting 1.

Comment: Also related: [How can I take a user inputted date instead of the current date in the Calendar class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554701/how-can-i-take-a-user-inputted-date-instead-of-the-current-date-in-the-calendar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing **09** as **Month** assuming it's **September** but actually in term of Calendar class it's **August** because months start from `00(Jan), 01(Feb)...` and so on in Calendar Class.

Hence in order to the get correct output you need to pass

```
08 // September Month not August
24
2018
```

Here is your [running code](https://ideone.com/LjgHJl)

Comment: Close. [October is 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.OCTOBER). And 24th October will be a Wednesday.

Comment: This is one of many reasons to **never use `Calendar`** class. See the modern solution in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482072/642706)

Answer (score 1):

Neeraj Jain has already in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473278/5772882) explained why you got the unexpected output. I should like to contribute the modern way of obtaining your result.

First, your users may prefer to enter the date on one line in a format of their own locale, for example `9/24/18` in the USA or `24/09/2018` in French. It’s not more complicated (when you know how):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
    String dateString = in.next();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    DayOfWeek dow = date.getDayOfWeek();
    String dowString = dow.getDisplayName(
                           TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE,
                           Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)
                       );
    System.out.println(dowString);
```

Here’s a sample run of the program in the US locale:

```
9/25/18
Tuesday
```

If you or your users do prefer to enter three separate numbers as in your program in the question:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month = in.nextInt();
    int day = in.nextInt();
    int year = in.nextInt();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```

Now we’ve got the `LocalDate`, the remainder is the same as before. A sample run:

```
9
27
2018
Thursday
```

Note that there’s no adding or subtracting of 1 anywhere because `LocalDate` numbers months the same way humans do. I am letting the scanner convert to integers, I find it a bit simpler than calling `Integer.parseInt`.

The `Calendar` class you were using is long outdated and poorly designed. I recommend you forget about the trouble with it and instead use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Excellent answer. In your code, I suggest breaking out the `getDayOfWeek` to its own line with a declared `DayOfWeek` variable. This might make it easier to follow, with less “magic”.

Answer (score 1):

By using `java.time.LocalDate` you can pass your 3 paramter (year, month, day) and get the dayOfWeek:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String month = in.next();
    String day = in.next();
    String year = in.next();

    System.out.println(getDay(day, month, year));
}

private static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
    return LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(year), Integer.valueOf(month), Integer.valueOf(day)).getDayOfWeek()
            .toString();
}
```

Comment: This code returns the name of the day-of-week in English in all-caps. Better to use [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) to automatically localize. See [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482072/642706).